# Zapped transaction, did rescan - bitcoin lost... :(

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, rescan

I made a transaction, realized the fee wasn't high enough, so I restarted Bitcoin-QT (MacOS) with -zapwallettxes, and removed the transaction.

Then restarted with -rescan, (been almost 24h since scan finished) but the funds are still missing. and there's no trace of the original transaction.

I don't find any trace of the transaction in the blockchain either...

Have I lost my funds? :-/

-- edit
When I import all the addresses from Bitcoin-Qt into Electrum, I can see all my funds... 
Bticoin-qt still has some missing.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. If the transaction is removed from the blockchain, it means it was never confirmed.

Thus the UTXO is still unspent, and should still be in your wallet. Are you sure your wallet is updated?

Maybe see if you can find the adresses by executing

`listreceivedbyaddress 0 true`

Or, if that doesn't show anything, dump all the private keys of your wallet and import them in something like electrum?

Comment: thanks.
I indeed find the address. The returned result is
    "address": "13gex5FmeNFLf4zdBbGqcdi65dPLE1efni",
    "account": "",
    "amount": 0.00000000,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "label": "",
    "txids": [
    ]

But no txid? Is that a good sign or bad? :)
I'll also try installing electrum...